# Is it good to define concrete classes inside abstract class?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I am reading a java code like this below,:
It defines concrete classes `ClientEntry`, `ConfirgurationEntry` inside abstract class `LogEntry`.

Is this a good practice?
Usually I define them in separate files.

```
public abstract class LogEntry {

    /**
     * The four allowed {@link LogEntry} types.
     */
    public static enum Type {

        /**
         * {@link LogEntry} with {@code index} = 0, {@code term} = 0.
         */
        SENTINEL,

        /**
         * {@link LogEntry} that stores a noop entry.
         */
        NOOP,

        /**
         * {@link LogEntry} that stores cluster membership information about the Raft cluster.
         */
        CONFIGURATION,

        /**
         * {@link LogEntry} that stores a {@link Command} submitted by a client.
         */
        CLIENT,
    }

    /**
     * Singleton instance of the {@link LogEntry.Type#SENTINEL} log entry.
     */
    public static final LogEntry SENTINEL = new LogEntry(Type.SENTINEL, 0, 0) {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Objects
                    .toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("type", "SENTINEL")
                    .add("index", getIndex())
                    .add("term", getTerm())
                    .toString();
        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //
    // Base class
    //

    private final Type type;
    private final long index;
    private final long term;

    // keeping this constructor private restricts
    // the number of allowed LogEntry types to those defined in this
    // compilation unit
    // i.e. using 'protected' instead would allow anyone to define additional
    // LogEntry types, which I don't support
    private LogEntry(Type type, long index, long term) {
        checkArgument(index >= 0, "index must be positive:%s", index);
        checkArgument(term >= 0, "term must be positive:%s", term);
        if (index == 0 && term == 0) {
            checkArgument(type == Type.SENTINEL);
        }
        this.type = type;
        this.index = index;
        this.term = term;
    }

    /**
     * Get the type of this log entry.
     *
     * @return {@link LogEntry.Type} of this log entry
     */
    public final Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Get the log entry's position in the 0-indexed Raft log.
     *
     * @return index >= 0 of this log entry's position in the Raft log
     */
    public long getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Get the election term in which this log entry was created.
     *
     * @return election term >= 0 in which this log entry was created
     */
    public final long getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(type, index, term);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        LogEntry other = (LogEntry) o;
        return type == other.type && index == other.index && term == other.term;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //
    // Subclasses
    //

    /**
     * {@code LogEntry} that contains a client {@link Command}.
     * <p/>
     * Once this entry is committed
     * the client is notified via {@link io.libraft.RaftListener#applyCommitted(Committed)}
     * that this {@code Command} can be applied locally.
     */
    public static final class ClientEntry extends LogEntry {

        private final Command command;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param index index > 0 of this log entry's position in the log
         * @param term election term > 0 in which this log entry was created
         * @param command instance of {@link Command} to be replicated
         */
        public ClientEntry(long index, long term, Command command) {
            super(Type.CLIENT, index, term);
            this.command = command;
        }

        /**
         * Get the {@link Command} to be replicated.
         *
         * @return instance of {@code Command} to be replicated
         */
        public Command getCommand() {
            return command;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(@Nullable Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

            ClientEntry other = (ClientEntry) o;
            return getType() == other.getType()
                    && getIndex() == other.getIndex()
                    && getTerm() == other.getTerm()
                    && command.equals(other.command);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(getType(), getIndex(), getTerm(), command);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Objects
                    .toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("type", getType())
                    .add("index", getIndex())
                    .add("term", getTerm())
                    .add("command", command)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

    // FIXME (AG): the design of this log entry is incorrect and has to be reworked
    /**
     * {@code LogEntry} that contains the
     * configuration state of the Raft cluster.
     */
    public static final class ConfigurationEntry extends LogEntry {

        private final Set<String> oldConfiguration;
        private final Set<String> newConfiguration;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param index index > 0 of this log entry's position in the log
         * @param term election term > 0 in which this log entry was created
         */
        public ConfigurationEntry(long index, long term, Set<String> oldConfiguration, Set<String> newConfiguration) {
            super(Type.CONFIGURATION, index, term);
            this.oldConfiguration = oldConfiguration;
            this.newConfiguration = newConfiguration;
        }

        public Set<String> getOldConfiguration() {
            return oldConfiguration;
        }

        public Set<String> getNewConfiguration() {
            return newConfiguration;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(@Nullable Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

            ConfigurationEntry other = (ConfigurationEntry) o;

            return getType() == other.getType()
                    && getIndex() == other.getIndex()
                    && getTerm() == other.getTerm()
                    && oldConfiguration.equals(other.oldConfiguration)
                    && newConfiguration.equals(other.newConfiguration);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(getType(), getIndex(), getTerm(), oldConfiguration, newConfiguration);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Objects
                    .toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("type", getType())
                    .add("index", getIndex())
                    .add("term", getTerm())
                    .add("oldConfiguration", oldConfiguration)
                    .add("newConfiguration", newConfiguration)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * noop {@code LogEntry}.
     * <p/>
     * {@code NoopEntry} is for {@link RaftAlgorithm}
     * internal use only. The client <strong>will not</strong>
     * be notified when a {@code NoopEntry} instance
     * is committed.
     */
    public static final class NoopEntry extends LogEntry {

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param index index > 0 of this log entry's position in the log
         * @param term election term > 0 in which this log entry was created
         */
        public NoopEntry(long index, long term) {
            super(Type.NOOP, index, term);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("type", getType())
                .add("index", getIndex())
                .add("term", getTerm())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the author has written a rich `enum` in an overly verbose way. IMO, `LogEntry` could simply be an `enum` in its own right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be honest. If I did this in work, my boss would probably take a blowtorch to my machine. But that is just because of the coding conventions within my workplace.

To quote the famous Jon Skeet

> My suggested name for this technique (including multiple top-level classes in a single source file) would be "mess". Seriously, I don't think it's a good idea - I'd use a nested type in this situation instead. Then it's still easy to predict which source file it's in. I don't believe there's an official term for this approach though.

The conventional wisdom is to stick to one class per file, especially if you're adding to an existing code base that follows this pattern. It's not *forbidden by the compiler*, but neither is:

```
int x = 4;
int y = (4 * x * 6 * x * 10 * x * 56 * x);
String s = "s" + "t" + "r" + "i" + "n" + "g";
```

Comment: The "blowtorch" bit made me laugh. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this practice, it's quite a bit easier to sort through multiple classes when they are in separate files. Some declare multiple classes in one file because they like the accessibility to the code. If you want to do this, which i recommend you don't, only one of the classes declared can be public (The public class should also contain the main method). If  you were to compile the code above you would have to remove 'public' from all but one class. When a code containing multiple classes is compiled, it creates multiple .class files (one for ever class declared in the source code). So even though the source code is all in one .java file, you will still end up with multiple class files.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in having a concrete class inside an abstract class. In fact there might be some circumstances when this approach will be best. Suppose you want all the subclasses of an abstract class to have access to a protected class that you define inside this abstract class.

Defining a static class is rare. It is mostly avoided. But we can see some example on java's package where static classes are present inside. But will be nothing different than having another class in different file except the heirarchy.